# Cast a list of objects to list of an interface type at runtime when target type is dynamic

Tags: c#, interface, casting, runtime

I have a method like this:

```
private static List<object> ConvertList<T>(IEnumerable<T> inputList, Type type)
{
   var innerType = type.GenericTypeArguments.First(); //innerType is like: MyInterface
   List<object> result1 = inputList.Select(item => Convert.ChangeType(item, innerType));
   return result1;
}
```

In above method at `runtime`:

- **`inputList`** parameter is: Something like `List<MyClass>`.
- **`type`** parameter is: Something like `type of List<MyInterface>`.

And definition of MyClass is like:

```
public class MyClass: MyInterface
{
   ...
}
```

The return value of above method is:  **`List<object>`**

**This method works well for me but i need its return value be base on its `type` parameter. for example i want the method return value be like: `List<MyInterface>`**

---

So i changed my method to this one:

```
private static dynamic ConvertList<T>(IEnumerable<T> inputList, Type type)
{
   var innerType = type.GenericTypeArguments.First(); //innerType is like: MyInterface
   List<object> result1 = inputList.Select(item => Convert.ChangeType(item, innerType));
   dynamic result2= Convert.ChangeType(result1, type);
   return result2;
}
```

But now i get the following error:

> Object must implement IConvertible

at this line of code:

```
 dynamic result2= Convert.ChangeType(result1, type);
```

I know the error reason but i don't know how to resolve this problem.

---

**Edit1:**

I think my way is incorrect, i should write some codes to change the following code `value type` to witch type i want base on `type` parameter at runtime:

```
var result1 = inputList.Select(item => Convert.ChangeType(item, innerType));
```

Now the question is how can i change or cast the type of above code (`result1`) **from `list<object>` to `list<MyInterface>`** when `list<MyInterface>` information is inside **`type` parameter** and the `type` parameter point to a list of `interface`, not a list of `class`???

Answer (score 1):

I think you should wrap the result1 to your object that implements a Iconvertible (bassicly to extend System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable by using composition) so it will be something like this:

```
    private static dynamic ConvertList<T>(IEnumerable<T> inputList, Type type)
    {
        var innerType = type.GenericTypeArguments.First(); //innerType is like: MyInterface
        Wrapper result1 = new Wrapper();
        result1.Property = inputList.Select(item => Convert.ChangeType(item, innerType));
        dynamic result2 = Convert.ChangeType(result1, type);
        return result2;
    }

    public class Wrapper : IConvertible
    {
        public System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object> Property { get; set; }

        //implement here all the methods required by Iconvertable
    }
```

Comment: I think my way is incorrect to extend it more, i appended an EDIT section to my question. plz read it...